# Run the same app on 2 web browsers / tabs on the same time ( Flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web, flutter-clippath

I am trying to run 2 different web instances of the same code (either chrome chrome or chrome edge). It's like with phone emulators (It's possible ofc, I can open 2 different emulators at the same time) but is it possible with web? If yes any ideas on how?
I still can run 1 chrome instance with F5 tho

I first run

```
flutter devices
```

it gives back 3 connected devices (Windows, Chrome, and Edge)
when I try to run

```
flutter run -d all
```

it gives back no devices found.

I am using Flutter 2.10 and "flutter doctor" has 0 issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run `-d all`, flutter thinks you are trying to run on a device called "all", which is not the case.

If you want to run the same app on multiple devices, I recommend you run the app multiple times, to do this, you will have to open your terminal multiple times, (if you are using windows terminal you can open multiple tabs and run on them like that)

Also keep in mind that when you run the app on the web, you are running it on your computer on a specific port, so let's say you want to run the app on both chrome and internet explorer, you can just run the app on chrome and then copy the URL at the top (should say something like `http://localhost:52955/`) and go to edge and paste the same URL.

If you want to run the same app on someone else's device (for example on two computers at the same time) you can replace `localhost` with your computer's network IP and you will have the same effect.

For obvious reasons the above only works on web.

Comment: Thank you so much, I copied the URL and got what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After running in the browser you can copy the url and paste it in the incognito screen of that browser, so you can open 2 tabs, also when using local storage, there is no duplicate :>